# How to print only a certain page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm using this [Printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package in my Flutter project to print my local PDF file. It’s working fine but I'm just wondering how can I print only a specific/certain page instead of the whole PDF.

In the body of my screen I'm using [Synfusion PDF View](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf) package and I pass widget.pageNumber to display a specific page that user selected.

I’m just wondering if there is a way to do that also in Printing package or other packages.

```
         IconButton(
            onPressed: _print,
            color: primaryText,
            icon: Icon(Icons.print_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
   
      body: SfPdfViewer.asset(
        'assets/data/song.pdf',
        initialZoomLevel: 3.0,
        controller: _pdfViewerController,
        onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
          _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(widget.pageNumber);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void _print() async {
  final pdf = await rootBundle.load('assets/data/song.pdf');
  await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => pdf.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart' as provider;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new pdf and copy the relevant page to the new pdf and print that document like

```dart
final PdfDocument newDocument = PdfDocument();
newDocument.pages.add():
//Load the existing PDF document.
final PdfDocument document =
    PdfDocument(inputBytes: File('input.pdf').readAsBytesSync());
//Get the existing PDF page.
final PdfPage page = document.pages[0];
newDocument.pages[0] = page;

await Printing.layoutPdf(
      onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => newDocument.save());
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a lot of error on some of the parameter so what package did you imported. I'm getting an error like 
"The named parameter 'inputBytes' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'inputBytes'"

Comment: import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart'; please add this on top

Comment: What do you get if you hover on pdf page format? It should give your a suggestion

Comment: I'm getting "Undefined class 'PdfPageFormat'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'PdfPageFormat'"

Comment: Pdfwidget as pw. If any of the codes belong to this pavkage please add pw as prefix